# While building in unity 25 weird errors appears

Tags: unity-game-engine

When I try to build a game 22 error appears, when I try to play in editor everything is OK.

I'm new to unity so sorry if I made some stupid mistake.

Errors:

> (Location)(): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'XXXX' does not exist in the namespace '' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

where XXXX is: GraphView (library UnityEditor.Experimental) , UIElements (library UnityEditor)

> (Location)): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'YYYY' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

YYYY = Edge, Node, Port, Direction, EditorWindow, MenuItemAttribute, MenuItem

and another one error

> UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+BuildMethodException: 20 errors at UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow+DefaultBuildMethods.BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions options)[0x002bb] in :0

Here's the code:

**DialogueGraphView**

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditor.Experimental.GraphView;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.UIElements;
using Button = UnityEngine.UIElements.Button;

public class DialogueGraphView : GraphView
{
        public readonly Vector2 DefaultNodeSize = new Vector2(200, 150);
        public readonly Vector2 DefaultCommentBlockSize = new Vector2(300, 200);
        public DialogueNode EntryPointNode;

        public DialogueGraphView(DialogueGraph editorWindow)
        {
            styleSheets.Add(Resources.Load<StyleSheet>("NarrativeGraph"));
            SetupZoom(ContentZoomer.DefaultMinScale, ContentZoomer.DefaultMaxScale);

            this.AddManipulator(new ContentDragger());
            this.AddManipulator(new SelectionDragger());
            this.AddManipulator(new RectangleSelector());
            this.AddManipulator(new FreehandSelector());

            var grid = new GridBackground();
            Insert(0, grid);
            grid.StretchToParentSize();

            AddElement(GetEntryPointNodeInstance());
        }

        public void CreateNewDialogueNode(string nodeName, Vector2 position)
        {
            AddElement(CreateNode(nodeName, position));
        }

        public DialogueNode CreateNode(string nodeName, Vector2 position)
        {
            var tempDialogueNode = new DialogueNode()
            {
                title = nodeName,
                DialogueText = nodeName,
                GUID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString()
            };
            tempDialogueNode.styleSheets.Add(Resources.Load<StyleSheet>("Node"));
            var inputPort = GetPortInstance(tempDialogueNode, Direction.Input, Port.Capacity.Multi);
            inputPort.portName = "Input";
            tempDialogueNode.inputContainer.Add(inputPort);
            tempDialogueNode.RefreshExpandedState();
            tempDialogueNode.RefreshPorts();
            tempDialogueNode.SetPosition(new Rect(position,
                DefaultNodeSize)); //To-Do: implement screen center instantiation positioning

            var textField = new TextField("");
            textField.RegisterValueChangedCallback(evt =>
            {
                tempDialogueNode.DialogueText = evt.newValue;
                tempDialogueNode.title = evt.newValue;
            });
            textField.SetValueWithoutNotify(tempDialogueNode.title);
            tempDialogueNode.mainContainer.Add(textField);

            var button = new Button(() => { AddChoicePort(tempDialogueNode); })
            {
                text = "Add Choice"
            };
            tempDialogueNode.titleButtonContainer.Add(button);
            return tempDialogueNode;
        }

        public void AddChoicePort(DialogueNode nodeCache, string overriddenPortName = "")
        {
            var generatedPort = GetPortInstance(nodeCache, Direction.Output);
            var portLabel = generatedPort.contentContainer.Q<Label>("type");
            generatedPort.contentContainer.Remove(portLabel);

            var outputPortCount = nodeCache.outputContainer.Query("connector").ToList().Count();
            var outputPortName = string.IsNullOrEmpty(overriddenPortName)
                ? $"Option {outputPortCount + 1}"
                : overriddenPortName;


            var textField = new TextField()
            {
                name = string.Empty,
                value = outputPortName
            };
            textField.RegisterValueChangedCallback(evt => generatedPort.portName = evt.newValue);
            generatedPort.contentContainer.Add(new Label("  "));
            generatedPort.contentContainer.Add(textField);
            var deleteButton = new Button(() => RemovePort(nodeCache, generatedPort))
            {
                text = "X"
            };
            generatedPort.contentContainer.Add(deleteButton);
            generatedPort.portName = outputPortName;
            nodeCache.outputContainer.Add(generatedPort);
            nodeCache.RefreshPorts();
            nodeCache.RefreshExpandedState();
        }

        private void RemovePort(Node node, Port socket)
        {
            var targetEdge = edges.ToList()
                .Where(x => x.output.portName == socket.portName && x.output.node == socket.node);
            if (targetEdge.Any())
            {
                var edge = targetEdge.First();
                edge.input.Disconnect(edge);
                RemoveElement(targetEdge.First());
            }

            node.outputContainer.Remove(socket);
            node.RefreshPorts();
            node.RefreshExpandedState();
        }

        private Port GetPortInstance(DialogueNode node, Direction nodeDirection,
            Port.Capacity capacity = Port.Capacity.Single)
        {
            return node.InstantiatePort(Orientation.Horizontal, nodeDirection, capacity, typeof(float));
        }

        private DialogueNode GetEntryPointNodeInstance()
        {
            var nodeCache = new DialogueNode()
            {
                title = "START",
                GUID = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
                DialogueText = "ENTRYPOINT",
                EntryPoint = true
            };

            var generatedPort = GetPortInstance(nodeCache, Direction.Output);
            generatedPort.portName = "Next";
            nodeCache.outputContainer.Add(generatedPort);

            nodeCache.capabilities &= ~Capabilities.Movable;
            nodeCache.capabilities &= ~Capabilities.Deletable;

            nodeCache.RefreshExpandedState();
            nodeCache.RefreshPorts();
            nodeCache.SetPosition(new Rect(100, 200, 100, 150));
            return nodeCache;
        }
}
```

**GraphSaveUtility**

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditor.Experimental.GraphView;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UIElements;

public class GraphSaveUtility
{
    private DialogueGraphView _targetGraphView;
    private DialogueContainer _containerCache;

    private List<Edge> Edges => _targetGraphView.edges.ToList();
    private List<DialogueNode> Nodes => _targetGraphView.nodes.ToList().Cast<DialogueNode>().ToList();
    public static GraphSaveUtility GetInstance(DialogueGraphView targetGraphView) {
        return new GraphSaveUtility {
            _targetGraphView = targetGraphView
        };
    }

    public void SaveGraph(string Filename) 
    {
        if(!Edges.Any()) return;

        var dialogueContainer = ScriptableObject.CreateInstance<DialogueContainer>();

        var connectedPorts = Edges.Where(x => x.input.node!=null).ToArray();

        for (var i = 0; i < connectedPorts.Length; i++) 
        {
            var outputNode = connectedPorts[i].output.node as DialogueNode;
            var inputNode = connectedPorts[i].input.node as DialogueNode;

            dialogueContainer.NodeLinks.Add(new NodeLinkData {
                BaseNodeGuid = outputNode.GUID,
                PortName = connectedPorts[i].output.portName,
                TargetNodeGuid = inputNode.GUID
            });
        }

        foreach(var DialogueNode in Nodes.Where(node=>!node.EntryPoint)) 
        {
            dialogueContainer.DialogueNodeData.Add(new DialogueNodeData{
                GUID = DialogueNode.GUID,
                DialogueText = DialogueNode.DialogueText,
                Position = DialogueNode.GetPosition().position
            });
        }

        if(!AssetDatabase.IsValidFolder("Assets/Resources"))
            AssetDatabase.CreateFolder("Assets", "Resources");

        AssetDatabase.CreateAsset(dialogueContainer, "Assets/Resources/{fileName}.asset");
        AssetDatabase.SaveAssets();
    }

    public void  LoadGraph(string Filename) {
        _containerCache = Resources.Load<DialogueContainer>(Filename);
        if(_containerCache == null) {
            EditorUtility.DisplayDialog("File not Found", "Target dialogue graph file does not exists!", "OK");
            return;
        }

        ClearGraph();
        CreateNodes();
        ConnectNodes();
    }

    private void ClearGraph() {
        Nodes.Find(x => x.EntryPoint).GUID = _containerCache.NodeLinks[0].BaseNodeGuid;

        foreach (var node in Nodes) {
            if (node.EntryPoint) return;

            Edges.Where(x => x.input.node==node).ToList()
            .ForEach(edge => _targetGraphView.RemoveElement(edge));

            _targetGraphView.RemoveElement(node);
        }
    }

private void ConnectNodes() {
    for (var i = 0; i < Nodes.Count; i++)  {
        var connections = _containerCache.NodeLinks.Where(x=> x.BaseNodeGuid == Nodes[i].GUID).ToList();
        for (var j = 0; j < connections.Count; j++) {
            var TargetNodeGuid = connections[j].TargetNodeGuid;
            var targetNode = Nodes.First( x => x.GUID == TargetNodeGuid);
            LinkNodes(Nodes[i].outputContainer[j].Q<Port>(), (Port) targetNode.inputContainer[0]);

            targetNode.SetPosition(new Rect(_containerCache.DialogueNodeData.First(x =>x.GUID==TargetNodeGuid).Position, _targetGraphView.DefaultNodeSize));
        }
    }
}

private void LinkNodes(Port output, Port input) {

    var tempEdge = new Edge {
        output = output,
        input = input
    };

    tempEdge.input.Connect(tempEdge);
    tempEdge.output.Connect(tempEdge);
    _targetGraphView.Add(tempEdge);

}


    private void CreateNodes() {
        foreach (var nodeData in _containerCache.DialogueNodeData) {
            var tempNode = _targetGraphView.CreateNode(nodeData.DialogueText, Vector2.zero);
            tempNode.GUID = nodeData.GUID;
            _targetGraphView.AddElement(tempNode);

            var nodePorts = _containerCache.NodeLinks.Where(x => x.BaseNodeGuid==nodeData.GUID).ToList();
            nodePorts.ForEach(x => _targetGraphView.AddChoicePort(tempNode, x.PortName));
        }
    }

}
```

**DialogueNode**

```css
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEditor.Experimental.GraphView;
using UnityEngine;

    public class DialogueNode : Node
    {
        public string DialogueText;
        public string GUID;
        public bool EntryPoint = false;
    }
```

**DialogueGraph**

```css
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using UnityEditor;
using UnityEditor.Experimental.GraphView;
using UnityEditor.UIElements;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UIElements;

    public class DialogueGraph : EditorWindow
    {
        private string _fileName = "New Narrative";

        private DialogueGraphView _graphView;
        private DialogueContainer _dialogueContainer;

        [MenuItem("Graph/Narrative Graph")]
        public static void CreateGraphViewWindow()
        {
            var window = GetWindow<DialogueGraph>();
            window.titleContent = new GUIContent("Narrative Graph");
        }

        private void ConstructGraphView()
        {
            _graphView = new DialogueGraphView(this)
            {
                name = "Narrative Graph",
            };
            _graphView.StretchToParentSize();
            rootVisualElement.Add(_graphView);
        }

        private void GenerateToolbar()
        {
            var toolbar = new Toolbar();

            var fileNameTextField = new TextField("File Name:");
            fileNameTextField.SetValueWithoutNotify(_fileName);
            fileNameTextField.MarkDirtyRepaint();
            fileNameTextField.RegisterValueChangedCallback(evt => _fileName = evt.newValue);
            toolbar.Add(fileNameTextField);

            toolbar.Add(new Button(() => RequestDataOperation(true)) {text = "Save Data"});

            toolbar.Add(new Button(() => RequestDataOperation(false)) {text = "Load Data"});
            // toolbar.Add(new Button(() => _graphView.CreateNewDialogueNode("Dialogue Node")) {text = "New Node",});
            rootVisualElement.Add(toolbar);
        }

        private void RequestDataOperation(bool save)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(_fileName))
            {
                var saveUtility = GraphSaveUtility.GetInstance(_graphView);
                if (save)
                    saveUtility.SaveGraph(_fileName);
                else
                    saveUtility.LoadGraph(_fileName);
            }
            else
            {
                EditorUtility.DisplayDialog("Invalid File name", "Please Enter a valid filename", "OK");
            }
        }

        private void OnEnable()
        {
            ConstructGraphView();
            GenerateToolbar();
            GenerateMiniMap();
        }

        private void GenerateMiniMap()
        {
            var miniMap = new MiniMap {anchored = true};
            var cords = _graphView.contentViewContainer.WorldToLocal(new Vector2(this.maxSize.x - 10, 30));
            miniMap.SetPosition(new Rect(cords.x, cords.y, 200, 140));
            _graphView.Add(miniMap);
        }

        private void OnDisable()
        {
            rootVisualElement.Remove(_graphView);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Editor stuff isnt available for final build

Comment: So I have to disable these scripts when I want to build a game?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As someone in the comments said, Unity can't build stuff that use the `UnityEditor` namespace. However, when building Unity will ignore everything located inside folders called "Editor". Put all those scripts that cause problems in a folder called "Editor" and it should compile with no errors.
You can also have more than one "Editor" folder, so if you need to differentiate between your editor scripts feel free to do that.